# SwiftUI problem with appended array in class where stocksData isn't showing custom stock in cartManager

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

My program works as follows, I add stock to stocksData and I add custom products to another array, when the pay function is called the stock.amount minuses the product depreciated amount.

My pay function detects stock I've added manually to the object but not the stock I've added with code.

The function also works to depreciate stock if the product stock name is the same

```
class StocksData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stocks: [(name: String, amount: Int, unit: String)] = []

    init() {
        // This is just a demo stock data initialization. You can replace it with your actual implementation.
        
        stocks.append(("Sugar", 500, "g"))
        
    }
}
```

CartManager:

```
@Published var stocksData: StocksData
@Published var productData = ProductData()

init(stocksData: StocksData) {
    self.stocksData = stocksData
    print(stocksData)

func pay() {

    print(stocksData.stocks)

    if let productStockName = product.stockName, let index = stocksData.stocks.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == productStockName }) {
        var stock = stocksData.stocks[index]
        if let depreciatedAmount = product.depreciatedAmount {
            stock.amount -= depreciatedAmount
            stocksData.stocks[index] = stock
        }
    }
}
```

StockInput

```
Button(action: {
    self.stocksData.stocks.append((name: self.stockName, amount: self.stockAmount, unit: self.units[self.unitSelection]))
    let cartManager = CartManager(stocksData: self.stocksData)

  
}, label: {
    Text("Add Stock")
})
```

Ive tried print statements to check the stockData array in all views and all custom products show up however in cartManager class it doesn't detect them and the output is as follows (first one being the pay function and the second a print statement in another view)

```
[(name: "Sugar", amount: 300, unit: "g")]
Project400.StocksData
Project400.StocksData
[(name: "Sugar", amount: 500, unit: "g"), (name: "S", amount: 100, unit: "g")]
Project400.StocksData
```

Comment: Some issues here, you are creating a CartManager object inside the button action so once that action is done the object is gone and you can't rely on @Published when accessing data from one ObservableObject from another ObservableObject, this property wrapper is to be accessed from views.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What should I use instead of published, thank you for your response as well

Comment: Although you don't show if your `CartManager` is an `ObservableObject` class, it is not 
a good idea to **nest** `ObservableObject` and use them in `@Published var stocksData: StocksData` as you do.
You are not using these classes the way they are meant to be used.
Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)